# Проблема с циклом в плюсах

Tags: c++

Я в плюсах новенький, по этому не понимаю в чем проблема. Есть вот такая задачка с циклом.

[image: скриншот формулы]

```
int i;
long double n;
cout << "Введите n: ";
cin >> n;
double S;
S = - 1/(1+1);
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0 ){
        S -= 1/(i+i*(i-1));
    } else {
        S += 1/(i+i*(i-1));
    }
}
cout << S << endl;

getch();
return 0;
```

Дебаггер показывает ошибку на строку после "if", а при работе пишет:

> Floating point exception (core dumped)

Объясните кто-то, в чем проблема

Comment: У вас происходит деление на 0 при i=0;

Comment: а вот этого я не заметил

Answer (score 6):

Должно быть как-то так:

```
double s=0, o=1, a=1, x;
unsigned i, n;

cin >> n >> x;

for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
  s += (o=-o) / (((a*=i)+i)*x);

cout << s;
```

А у тебя:

- Деление целочисленное
- Формула неправильная
- Потерялся `x`

Comment: оу, спасибо большое. возьму на заметку

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень странное задание. В первом члене x вообще нет, во втором и далее - просто x, без степени. Очень слабо верится, что все так и есть.

Но если так... То достаточно написать

```
double x;
cin >> x;
cout << -0.5-0.25/x;
```

Если же потеряны степени и при (2+2) просто x, потом x^2, при (24+6) - x^3, то

```
cout << -0.5+0.25/x;
```

У вас же надо найти сумму, а в ней предел не указан...

Если уточните задачу - можно будет написать и более точный ответ...